# Read and change file information by specific way in C

Tags: c, file

I want to read information from file and change it... 
For example i have data which is :

```
city dog name house 4ever
cat 2man tree five
```

Must left only a words which based on characters (can't be numbers).

I know how to read file, but then i don't know how to change anything
This is my code to read file :

Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char ch;
   FILE *file;

   file = fopen("testfile.txt", "r"); // read mode

   if( file == NULL )
   {
      perror("Klaida. Failo negalima atidaryti.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   printf("Failo duomynys yra:\n");

   while( ( ch = fgetc(file) ) != EOF )
      printf("%c",ch);

   fclose(file);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Huge Hint: the opposite of `fgetc` is ... `fputc`! Ta-daa!

Answer (score 0):

I would ***strongly*** suggest to you that you use `read`/`write` from `unistd.h` header. The method you chose here is quite...primitive. Anyway, here's how you should go about it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char ch;
   FILE *file;
   FILE *file_write;

   file = fopen("testfile.txt", "r"); // read mode
   file_write = fopen("testfile_write.txt", "w");
   if( file == NULL )
   {
      perror("Klaida. Failo negalima atidaryti.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   printf("Failo duomynys yra:\n");

   while( ( ch = fgetc(file) ) != EOF ) {
        if (ch == '4') {
                fputc('f', file_write);
                fputc('o', file_write);
                fputc('u', file_write);
                fputc('r', file_write);
        }
        else if (ch == '2') {
                fputc('t', file_write);
                fputc('w', file_write); 
                fputc('o', file_write);
        }
        else 
                fputc(ch, file_write);
   }

   fclose(file);
   return 0;
}
```